# wait until the task completed in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

in this code there is 10 button and when i tap on them count to 60 sec

i want to like wait
like two in same time and other wait
like when i tap the first button than pressed the secound button  these are going , when i pressed the third button and forth button , third button and fourth button wait for the first and secound button when one of the first or secound button reach the 60 the third button start and fourh button wait untill one of the running button reath the 60 than start and goes on

```
  class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
 }

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
List<int> buttonCounts = List<int>.filled(10, 0);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Button Counter'),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: buttonCounts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('Button ${index + 1}'),
          subtitle: Text('Count: ${buttonCounts[index]}'),
          trailing: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Tap'),
            onPressed: () {
              if (buttonCounts[index] < 60) {
                incrementCounter(index);
              }
            },
          ),
        );
      },
     ),
     ),
    );
    }

 void incrementCounter(int index) async {
  while (buttonCounts[index] < 60) {
   // Delay for 1 second before incrementing the counter
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  setState(() {
     buttonCounts[index]++;
     });
    }
    }
    }
```

i did this but doesnt work

```
void startCounting(int index) async {
isButtonRunning[index] = true;
setState(() {});

await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

while (buttonCounts[index] < 60) {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  setState(() {
    buttonCounts[index]++;
  });
}

isButtonRunning[index] = false;

if (index < 2) {
  if (isButtonRunning[2]) {
    startCounting(3);
  }
  if (isButtonRunning[3]) {
    startCounting(2);
  }
}
```

we can look in this way to like

just like this example
the running button when i tap on them be in the list and that list just has 2 lenght
like when i press the 1 button and 2 button the two of them be in that list and when i press the 3or 4or 5or etc they should wait until one of them  reach the 60 exit that list and place them for 3 or 4 and i want just that 2 lenth list is work

Answer (score 0):

I've fully explained your case as below

1. Add a new list called `activeButtons` to keep track of the currently active buttons.
2. Modify the `onPressed` callback of the buttons to check if there are less than two active buttons and the current button is not already in the `activeButtons` list.
3. When a button is tapped, add it to the `activeButtons` list and start counting.
4. Once a button completes its count, remove it from the `activeButtons` list.
5. Allow another button to start counting if there are less than two active buttons available.
6. Repeat the process until all buttons have completed their counts.

Please modify your code as below provided code:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<int> buttonCounts = List<int>.filled(10, 0);
  List<int> activeButtons = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Button Counter'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: buttonCounts.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('Button ${index + 1}'),
              subtitle: Text('Count: ${buttonCounts[index]}'),
              trailing: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Tap'),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (activeButtons.length < 2 && !activeButtons.contains(index)) {
                    startCounting(index);
                  }
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void startCounting(int index) async {
    activeButtons.add(index);
    setState(() {});

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    while (buttonCounts[index] < 60) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      setState(() {
        buttonCounts[index]++;
      });
    }

    activeButtons.remove(index);

    if (activeButtons.length < 2) {
      for (int i = 0; i < buttonCounts.length; i++) {
        if (!activeButtons.contains(i)) {
          startCounting(i);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work  
i tap on three button with time distance two of them reach the 60 after that the buttons doesn't work

Comment: none of them after that count